# DropDownList with repeated data value fields OnSelected get confused and chooses the first one why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, types

**Current Issue:** My DropDownList is provided with DataTextField="COLUMNS_NAME" DataValueField="DATA_TYPE" properties, the DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged() does not retain the text based on the selected input. But it retains the first value from the list of items

**Solution Required:** How to Retain the selected input text based on the DATA_TYPE property ? **I tried storing the Session["DDLValue"] = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text** but it always retains the first value from the list of items which satisfies the respective DATA_TYPE present in an Index.

i.e. if i choose **"e"** from The following DropDownList inputs the value retained in DropDownList is **"d"**

How to retain **"e"**

```
COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE  
a            decimal
b            decimal
c            decimal
d            int
e            int
f            varchar
g            varchar  
h            varchar
i            varchar
j            varchar
```

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="MySqlDataSource">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MySqlDataSource" runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDropDownLists();
    }
}

private void BindDropDownLists()
{
    MySqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connection;
    MySqlDataSource.SelectCommand =  "SELECT DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE ))as DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'RESULT' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','column2','Column3'))";

    DropDownList5.DataTextField = "COLUMN_NAME";
    DropDownList5.DataValueField = "DATA_TYPE";
    DropDownList5.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: where are you filling the drop down, is it on the page load ?

Comment: May be you are filling the `dropdown` list again before getting the values from the `dropdown` list.

Comment: share drop down filling method code

Comment: @KumarManish added Server side and client side code.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ Shared my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After render , your drop down list is look like below , **need to use unique value field  for proper selection**[image]

Comment: you can use this query (select COLUMN_NAME + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME )) from col), when you insert into database , split it after "_" and make proper data in the database

Comment: Could you please add the sql query in the BindDropDownList() function for SqlDatasource.SelectCommand ?

Comment: try this SELECT COLUMN_NAME + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ))as COLUMN_NAME , DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (TABLE_NAME = 'RESULT' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','column2','Column3'))

Comment: @ Kumar Manish for varchar and datetime data value field it retains correctly but for decimal input the problem still occurs how to handle for all the datatypes.

Comment: what type of issues came out during decimal value ?

Comment: @ Kumar Manish it retains the first value again for decimal inputs. I have varchar, decimal and datetime datavalue fields in DDL

Comment: try this query SELECT DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE ))as DATA_TYPE  + ' _ ' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (TABLE_NAME = 'RESULT' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','column2','Column3'))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52284/discussion-between-shrivatsan-and-kumar-manish)

Comment: Could you please provide the sql query i.e change the above query to select information_schema.columns from two different sql database tables?

Answer (score 1):

I think the you should have unique values for the dropdown. You could try to fabricate the values which you could uniquely identify. Something like:

```
COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE
a            a_decimal
b            b_decimal
c            c_decimal
d            d_int
e            e_int
f            f_varchar
g            g_varchar
h            h_varchar
i            i_varchar
j            j_varchar
```

A solution like this will ensure that you have unique values in your dropdown. The reason for using this is that creating `DATA_TYPE` string and extracting the actual value from it very simple. Just combine `COLUMN_NAME` and `DATA_TYPE` with underscore and split on underscore whenever the actual value is required.

> The crux: You should try to have unique value for the dropdown. It could be an ID or some other unique value.
>
> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy paste solution.

Comment: i have changed my select command to combine could you please comment if i am doing right ?

Comment: Well, if you are doing it right your problem should get resolved automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have duplicate values in `data value field` the problem is occurring. It is looking for the first match and selecting it.

If you want to continue with this then you may prefix some auto-increment integer and add it in value field and use `substring` to get the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Solution : Thanks to @Kumar Manish comments

Select Command inside the BindDropDownLists()

```
private void BindDropDownLists()
     {
         SqlDataSource.ConnectionString = connection;

         SqlDataSource.SelectCommand= "SELECT DATA_TYPE + '_' + convert(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA_TYPE ))as DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'RESULT' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1','column2','Column3'))";
         DropDownList5.DataTextField = "COLUMN_NAME";
         DropDownList5.DataValueField = "DATA_TYPE";
         DropDownList5.DataBind();
     }
```

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Yes its able to retain the DDL value now based on uniquely generated datavalue fields